# $k$-connected graph and the connectivity of the graph.

Tags: graph-theory

- A $\textbf{separating}$ set of a graph $G$ is a set $S \subseteq V(G)$ such that $G-S$ is disconnected.
- The $\textbf{connectivity}$ of a graph $G$ is the minimum size of the separating  set.
- A graph $G$ is $k$-connected if its connectivity is atleast $k$. Moreover, A graph other than complete graph is $k$-connected iff every separating set has atleast $k$ and the connectivity of complete graph $K_n$ is $n-1$.

I am reading the book $\textbf{The introduction of graph theory by Douglas B. West}$

I think the connectivity of a $k$- connected  graph is $k$, but i have seen the question in excercise that

> > every graph with connectivity $4$ is $2$-connected.

The minimum number of vertices whose deletion disconnects $G$ is $4$.Thus the size of every separating set has size atleast $4$. so the connectivity of $G$ is $4$.

I am confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's a rather simple problem. Basically all it requires is the understanding that a graph being $k$-connected also implies that it is also $k-1$-connected. I think you're confusing yourself by overthinking since it really is that simple.

Comment: Firstly,thanks for the prompt reply. Can we say if the connectivity of a graph $G$ is $r$ , then $G$ is $r-i$ connected, where $0 \leq i \leq r-1$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.